# PHP convert serialized JSON to array

Tags: php, json

PHP:

```
$ids = json_decode(["1","3"]);
$ID = implode(",", array_map('intval', $ids));
print_r($ID);
```

Anyone can please tell me How can I convert serialized JSON to array? Why is this program not working?

Comment: it won't work for many reasons..

Comment: @ArtOsi can you please explain one How can I make it workable?

Comment: you need pass json string to the json_decode

Comment: first of all `json_decode` input param should be string, not array so `json_decode('["1","3"]');`, and then `$ids` doesn't have index 'ID', which as I see you already fixed. And then i don't understand why you mapping your array values to int if you then implode them to string anyway?

Comment: Posted a solution to your question give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look into documentation of [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), you will see that $json must be a string type.

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth
>   = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )

So your code should look like this:

```
$ids = json_decode('["1","3"]');
$ID = implode(",", array_map('intval', $ids));
print_r($ID);
```

Comment: this is not supposed to be an answer

Comment: Given the questions - "*How can I convert serialized JSON to array?*" and "*Why is this program not working?*" - this looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @salathe now with explanation and example it looks like one. But before it was more like comment.

Comment: When I commented, it was a bad answer, but still an answer. It has since been improved, to everyone's benefit. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$ids = json_decode(json_encode(["1","3"],true),true);
$ID = implode(",", array_map('intval', $ids));
print_r($ID);
```

You need to encode it first to json and then decode it. Don't forget the `,true` it's important.

Output is `1,3`